# Libvirt virDomainGetInfo() results in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, libvirt

I am following an example from Libvirt's documentation to list all domains using [virConnectListAllDomains](https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-domain.html#virConnectListAllDomains). The function is working, and it shows the correct number of active domains. Now I am trying to use [virDomainGetInfo](https://libvirt.org/html/libvirt-libvirt-domain.html#virDomainGetInfo) to print information about domain but I am getting a segmentation fault. Below is the code and following is the output from the program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libvirt/libvirt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    
    virConnectPtr conn;
    
    virDomainPtr *domains;  
    unsigned int flags = VIR_CONNECT_LIST_DOMAINS_ACTIVE;
    int ret;
    
    conn = virConnectOpen("qemu:///system");


    if (conn == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open connection to qemu:///system\n");
    }else
    {
            printf("Sucessfully connected\n");
    }

    ret = virConnectListAllDomains(conn,&domains,flags);
    
    if(ret < 0 )
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to Get the List of Domains\n");
    }else
    {
        printf("I have domain info of %d domains\n", ret );
    }

    
    for( int i = 0; i < ret; i++)
    {
        
        virDomainInfoPtr domainInfo;
        int virRet;
        virRet = virDomainGetInfo(domains[i], domainInfo);
    
        if(virRet < 0 )
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to Get the Domain Info\n");
        }else
        {
            printf("State  : %c",domainInfo->state);
            printf("maxMem : %lu",domainInfo->maxMem);
            printf("memory : %lu",domainInfo->memory);
            printf("nVRCPU : %u",domainInfo->nrVirtCpu);
            printf("cpuTime: %llu",domainInfo->cpuTime);
            
        }
        virDomainFree(domains[i]);      
    }
    free(domains);
    virConnectClose(conn);
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
Sucessfully connected
I have domain info of 1 domains
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Your pasted code seems to be duplicated / otherwise corrupted in the middle. (The if and the for loop appear twice and interleaved.)

Comment: You're passing `domainInfo` and expecting that it be modified by `virDomainGetInfo()`. You're supposed to pass a pointer to a structure which that function will fill in.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart thank you for pointing out the formatting error, I have change it. `domainInfo` is of type `virDomainInfoPtr`. According to the documentation, `virDomainInfoPtr` is defined as `typedef virDomainInfo * virDomainInfoPtr`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the structure to be filled in,
Change:

```
    virDomainInfoPtr domainInfo;
    int virRet;
    virRet = virDomainGetInfo(domains[i], domainInfo);
```

To:

```
    virDomainInfo domainInfo;
    int virRet;
    virRet = virDomainGetInfo(domains[i], &domainInfo);
```